# Assign Javadoc location to maven managed dependencies in Eclipse, where Javadoc is manually installed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I downloaded the jdk api doc from oracle site, and really want to see it when i use content assistant...

Since "javaee-api" javadoc is not available in public repo, so i manually installed it to the local repo using command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jdk-6-javadoc-all.zip -DgroupId=javax 
  -DartifactId=javaee-api -Dversion=6.0 -Dpackaging=zip -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

Then I tried:

1. unzip the jdk, and re-zip only the api document, to ensure the "package-info" something is on the top level inside the zip file
2. then I assign the javadoc location from project->properties->java build path....
   but every time i do "OK" and close the dialogue, the javadoc location switched back to "none" automatically...

So I created a new project without maven and add the javaee-api.jar into the project, attach the javadoc... and the javadoc is shown as i typed in my test java file.

But still, it shows no javadoc in all the maven managed projects... even after i restarted the eclipse, clean&install from prompt, delete and re-import the project... it's not working!

related maven dependency xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have search a lot in the web including stackoverflow here, but still not wokring~ It really make me headache.... Anyone has the solution?

Comment: Which javaee-api artifact are you using? groupId, artifactId, version?

Comment: <groupId>javax</groupId>     <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>     <version>6.0</version>     <scope>provided</scope>     and i downloaded the entire JDK api document from oracle site. if i created a regular eclipse project, and pointed the javadoc, the content will display correctly when i'm typeing the related API. but for maven managed project, it will always set the javadoc location to "none"

Answer (score 1):

Let you have dependency in your pom file:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
<version>6.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Download javadoc from http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/java_ee_sdk/6u2-nojdk/javadoc-6.0.1.jar to current folder.

Install javadoc:

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=javadoc-6.0.1.jar -DgroupId=javax -DartifactId=javaee-api -Dversion=6.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dclassifier=javadoc

Now you can open Maven Dependency, right click at javaee-api-6.0.jar, select Maven > Open JavaDoc.

(If you use NetBeans you can see J letter near javaee-api-6.0.jar package)

Comment: The link you provided is broken now. Where can I find the current file?